# white space on my navbar that I dont define in css?

Tags: css, html, navbar

I have been working on this navbar for a little while now and i fixed some of it (it was really bad before) but there is still white space (there are other topics on here related to this but not this problem or the answers didn't work).  Is it something I am forgetting to do? Am I setting a margin and I just don't see it?

What it looks like: http://www.orikina.com/hm/

Css:

```
    .nav {
    width: 100%;
    height: 35px;
    background-color:#2D2D2D;
    border-bottom: #000000;
    border-width: 1px;
    float: left;
}
.nav, ul{
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.nav, ul, li{
    display:inline;
}
.nav, ul, li, a{
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 17px;
    color: #BBBBBB;
    display: inline-block;
}
.nav, ul, li, a:hover{
    color:#FFFFFF;
}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/m.styles.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="nav">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- End of NAVBAR -->
    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance! -Tim

Comment: Were you able to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is due to the default margin set for the body by the user agent(in Chrome 8px). So you can just set `margin-top:0px;` on body.

```
body {
    margin-top: 0px; //if you just want to remove the top margin.
}
```

Snapshot:

[image]

You can prefer doing a **[CSS reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)** always to make sure default styles are not rendered.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `body { padding: 0; }` to remove it's padding.

Comment: I have done this before, and I set it again, nothing has changed.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to remove the base whitespace around your navbar, then set the margin to `0px`; which you can set by doing the following:

```
body {
  margin: 0px;
}
```

Here's a simple example: http://jsfiddle.net/uMExn/

If you're trying to remove just the top margin or others, then you can potentially use:

```
body {
  margin-top: 0px; //remove just the top margin
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

or:

```
body {
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}
```

Where the sequence of padding items above is: top, right, bottom, left.

Answer (score 0):

All of the answers so far are correct, I just want to add that one of the first things I always add to my base CSS file or expect out of a reset CSS file is this

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

If you plan on being a front end web developer for any significant amount of time you would be doing yourself a favor to learn the built in developer tools of your browser of choice. My recommendation is to use either Chrome of Firefox for your primary development and then just test in IE as needed since their developer tools are more advanced than those in IE. If you use Firefox I would highly recommend the firebug extension. If you are using Chrome Google has made a course on getting to know the Chrome Developer Tools: http://discover-devtools.codeschool.com/ which would be a great place to start.